# Python Scapy - Meaningful Interfaces Name

Tags: python, scapy, network-interface

I'm building a sniffer with python 2.6 and Scapy on windows 7. When the user wants to start a sniff I give him the option to choose the interface he wants to sniff in, this gives me the interfaces -

```
def get_interfaces():
    """returns a list of available network interfaces"""
    interfaces = []
    for iface_name in sorted(ifaces.data.keys()):
        dev = ifaces.data[iface_name]
        mac = str(dev.mac)
        mac = conf.manufdb._resolve_MAC(mac)

        i = Interface(
            name=str(dev.name).ljust(4),
            ip=dev.ip.ljust(15),
            mac=mac.upper()
        )
        interfaces.append(i)
    return interfaces
```

Interface is a class I built to pass data about the interfaces easily.
My question is why are the names always **'ethX'**, what does it mean? how can I convert it to something more meaningful like **'Wireless Network Connection'** or **'VirtualBox Host-Only Network'** like Wireshark does?

Comment: Those names have some meaning

ethX means Ethernet, The number(X) is the index of the many possible. So you may have eth0, eth1, .
Wireless cards have wl0 and so on
The local interface is mostly lo0
You can possibly build a mapping of these, But its exhaustive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ethX is the traditional way to list ETHernet devices on Linux. I recomend you to read this [explanation on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125400/how-can-i-find-available-network-interfaces)

As for getting the Human Name of the Interface, well that's a major trick to do from Python.
Mi first recommendation is to look at the implementation of ifaces in [Scapy repository](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/). There you will be able to determine every data you can access.

The hard and good way to do it, will be accessing the WinAPI trough a parser for python. much easier (and dirty) way will be getting the names trough a headless powershell and mapping that to your addresses.

Any way, you choosed a defiant project. :)